# Possible incompatibility - LaTeX3 kernel and EbGaramond.sty

Tags: latex3, ebgaramond

In advance, I apologise if this is off-topic as "too localised", but I'm not sure where's the best place to ask.

I am running TeX Live 2014 on Windows 7, fully up-to-date as of this morning. Here's my MWE:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\begin{document}
Hello, World!
\end{document}
```

which gives me this (partial) log:

```
! LaTeX error: "kernel/misplaced-equals-sign"
! 
! Misplaced equals sign in key-value input 81
! 
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.81       {EBGaramond12}
```

The l.81 in question appears to come from this part of ebgaramond.sty:

```
  \setmainfont
      [ Numbers = {\ebgaramond@figurealign,\ebgaramond@figurestyle},
        UprightFont    = *-Regular ,
        ItalicFont     = *-Italic ,
        BoldFont    = *-Regular ,
        BoldItalicFont     = *-Italic ,
      ]
      {EBGaramond12}
```

For EBGaramond problems, I would normally talk with Bob Tennent, but can't help feeling this case is something else.

Please, a clue, or suggest additional useful diagnostics. I don't *think* I have a corrupted install, as I installed clean from the ISO three days ago, and did just one `tlmgr update --all` this morning.

---

And here's the `\listfiles`:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
ebgaramond.sty    2014/07/02 (Bob Tennent) Style file for EB Garamond fonts.
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 xkeyval.sty    2014/05/25 v2.7 package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/05/25 v2.7 key=value parser (HA)
textcomp.sty    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
fontspec.sty    2014/06/21 v2.4a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
   expl3.sty    2014/06/10 v5105 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2014/06/10 v5105 L3 programming layer 
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
l3xdvipdfmx.def    
  xparse.sty    2014/06/10 v5105 L3 Experimental document command parser
fontspec-patches.sty    2014/06/21 v2.4a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
X
fontspec-xetex.sty    2014/06/21 v2.4a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 fontenc.sty
  eu1enc.def    2010/05/27 v0.1h Experimental Unicode font encodings
  eu1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
xunicode.sty    2011/09/09 v0.981 provides access to latin accents and many oth
er characters in Unicode lower plane
 eu1lmss.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
graphicx.sty    2014/04/25 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
   xetex.def    2014/04/28 v4.01 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (RRM/JK)

fontspec.cfg
ebgaramond12.fontspec
ebgaramond12.fontspec
ebgaramond12.fontspec
ebgaramond12.fontspec
ebgaramond12.fontspec
ebgaramond12.fontspec
ebgaramond12.fontspec
  ts1cmr.fd    1999/05/25 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
   t3cmr.fd    2001/12/31 TIPA font definitions
```

### ***********

And here are the actual file paths from the .log:

```
(d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
(d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
(d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ebgaramond/ebgaramond.sty
(d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty
(d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
(d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
(d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
(d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def
(d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex
(d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty
(d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3xdvipdfmx.def
(d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-patches.sty
) (d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1enc.def
(d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1lmr.fd
(d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xunicode/xunicode.sty
(d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tipa/t3enc.def
(d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1lmss.fd
(d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
(d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg
(d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-def/xetex.def
(d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ebgaramond/ebgaramond12.fontspec)
(d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ebgaramond/ebgaramond12.fontspec)
(d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ebgaramond/ebgaramond12.fontspec)
(d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ebgaramond/ebgaramond12.fontspec)
(d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ebgaramond/ebgaramond12.fontspec)
(d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ebgaramond/ebgaramond12.fontspec)
(d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ebgaramond/ebgaramond12.fontspec)
(d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
(d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tipa/t3cmr.fd
```

---

And here's `ebgaramond12.fontspec`. Looks innocuous:

```
  \defaultfontfeatures{
        Extension = .otf 
        UprightFont    = *-Regular ,
        ItalicFont     = *-Italic ,
        BoldFont    = *-Regular ,
        BoldItalicFont     = *-Italic
   }
```

Comment: All 'works for me' here: can we see the file locations/versions from your `.log`?

Comment: `ebgaramond12.fontspec` looks suspicious: what's in it?

Comment: @JosephWright Added!

Comment: On my sistem I have `EBGaramond12.fontspec` that's not loaded when running XeLaTeX on the example file.

Comment: On the other hand, that `.fontspec` file is wrong, as it is missing a comma after `Extension = .otf`

Comment: @egreg File added! Could the difference be that I have the otfs installed as windows fonts, too?

Comment: @Brent.Longborough As you see it's *not* innocuous: it contains a syntax error! On the other hand I'm curious why it is not loaded on my system.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `fontspec` package allows for “collections” (see section 6.2 in the doc): a `.fontspec` file containing font definitions can be written and stored. However, `fontspec` *lowercases* the argument when looking for the `.fontspec` file, so with

```
\setmainfont{EBGaramond12}
```

the file looked for is `ebgaramond12.fontspec`. To make things hairier, the distribution of the `ebgaramond` package contains `EBGaramond12.fontspec`. On a case sensitive file system, this is not loaded because it's not looked for; to the contrary, a case insensitive file system (Windows) will find it and, indeed, you get entries

```
ebgaramond12.fontspec
```

in the file list.

Alas, the file contains a syntax error, besides being ill-named:

```
  \defaultfontfeatures{
        Extension = .otf ,% <---------------- MISSING COMMA!
        UprightFont    = *-Regular ,
        ItalicFont     = *-Italic ,
        BoldFont    = *-Regular ,
        BoldItalicFont     = *-Italic
   }
```

If I copy `EBGaramond12.fontspec` as `ebgaramond12.fontspec` in the work directory, I get the same error message as you. This error disappears as soon as I add the missing comma as shown above.

Comment: Curious! ebgaramond12.fontspec is listed in the eggaramond tlpobj file, but is *not* in the package tar.xz, nor in the package on CTAN??? How is it created?

Comment: @egreg:  In the only example in the fontspec documentation, a file is named TeXGyreAdventor.fontspec. The missing comma is the real issue.

Comment: @user51830 It's not the only flaw in the manual. However, the package should try both the unchanged argument and the lowercased one.

Comment: @egreg — Hmm, now why would I lowercase the font name in general? I have no memory of why this would be necessary!